# Convert a week number into a Month

Tags: php, excel, date

How to convert a week number to a month ?

For example, 162 weeks = 37,26 Month (so 37 Months if we around the number).

Have you an idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that is almost trivial depenging on the accuracy you need

```
$days = $weeks * 7;
$months = floor($days/30);
```

Comment: Precise date/time calculations are **never** trivial.

Comment: it is regarding the difficulty of the calculation

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [DateTime object](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) for this. Create a new date, that starts on january first, then use the add method, using a DateInterval object of x weeks (`new DateInterval('P' . $num . 'W');`), then format the date object using [the month character](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

Comment: Thanks, I keep this fix for the future.

Answer (score 0):

If you need an average value:

```
return $numberOfWeeks * 0.229984378;
```

Source: http://www.google.com/search?q=1%20week%20in%20months=

(However, bear in mind that the number of weeks in a month is not constant. 1 month may contain 4 to 4.4 weeks.)

Answer (score 0):

1 month is `4.34812141` weeks.

So it would be:

```
$months = $weeks / 4.34812141;
```

If you want to round it up. You need to:

```
echo (int)$months;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
months =  (weeks * 7) / 30
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to have a starting date: eg. 162 weeks from ....

Comment: this only depends on the accuracy required. if it doesn't mather how accurate it is then 30 days for one month is accurate enough because the average is about 30.416 days a month